Unable to type in text field with overlay
I'm trying to design a text field to which I applied an .overlay modifier to have a background. This text field is inside an HStack with an image and the text field itself. Applying the .overlay to have a background makes it unable to type into, whereas without it, I can. Here's the source code:
ZStack {
                Color.black // This sets the entire background to black
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack(spacing: 0){
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "person.text.rectangle.fill")
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        TextField("Display Name...", text: $name)
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .foregroundStyle(.gray).opacity(0.2) // Change the color to gray
                    )
                    .padding()
                    
                }
                
            }```

Image of view:


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/ZNVQlfmS.png


As the name implies, overlay goes on top and blocks the inputs, whereas background goes in the background.
So change .overlay(...) to .background(...) to add the desired background to your HStack.

if my answer helped you consider accepting it by ticking the tick mark next to it, it turns green.

yes it helps, i ticked it. Thank you again.
